# JList not showing items

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I got some problems showing the items of a JList.

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
model.addElement("one");
model.addElement("two");
model.addElement("three");

list = new JList<String>(model);
list.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer());
list.setVisible(true);
```

I also tried it without setting a `ListCellRenderer`, still no luck.

Can you suggest me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Show how you add `JList` to container(`JPanel`/`JFrame`).

Comment: "I got some problems" - what are the problems? Describe them.

Comment: Please expand your example to a **minimal**, compilable program that demonstrates this problem. It's not clear from your short code where the problem lies. Nor have you explained what problem, exactly, you are experiencing.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  (What @Duncan suggested, but with links.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your anwsers and comments. The problem was that no list item where shown.

In future I will add a minimal compilable program.

My problem was caused by trying to add a `JPanel` to a `JDialog` in the constructor, but the `JPanel` was `null` at this moment because it got initialized in the `createUIComponents` method.

A beginner begs your pardon.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
public class JListTest implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JListTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        frame.add(getComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    Component getComponent() {
        DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
        model.addElement("one");
        model.addElement("two");
        model.addElement("three");

        JList<String> list = new JList<>(model);
        list.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer());
        list.setVisible(true);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Down-vote from me. We've only been given a tiny piece of code. Throwing that into an entire program and proving it works *in your context* doesn't really help the OP. Let's find out what's going on in his application and then help him fix it.